# What are and how to prevent these maggots in my lovage?

Tags: pest-control, pests

When harvesting some of my lovage I noticed that some foilage has dried out or has large yellow spots. In one of the leave I saw an inhabitant - see below. This maggot was inside the leave: on both side there was still a layer.

What is this maggot and how can I prevent its parents to infiltrate my the leaves? Preferably in an organic way.

The maggot is located in the yellow bubble in the center of the leave on the right side.

[image]

After I ejected the maggot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the larval form of a leaf mining insect - control of these, even with pesticides, isn't very effective, and as you don't want to use pesticides anyway, the only thing you can do is pick off affected leaves as soon as you see them. If the problem becomes widespread, then a cover over the crop is about the only way to keep the flying leaf miner from leaving its eggs inside the leaves. Lovage is often affected by these pests.